# Unable to See Button(s) in an inflated View

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I had created AlertDialog by inflating the following XML:

```
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_logs, null);
    ListView list = (ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.listDates);
```

**The full code for showing alertDialog is**:

```
private void showLogs(final List<Absentees> abs) {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_logs, null);
    ListView list = (ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.listDates);
    list.setAdapter(new CustomAdapterTagAbsentees(this,abs));
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,int position, long id) {
                Absentees a =(Absentees)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                try
                {
                    showLogDetails(a);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    show_popup(e+"");
                }
            }   

        });
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Attendance Details:");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Day : ");
    alertDialogBuilder
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("Dismiss",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
  AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
  alertDialog.show();
}
```

**The Layout Used :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
>
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listDates"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="20sp"     
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**About My Problem:**

if the List is small enough to fit the screen I can see "Dismiss" button(The positiveButton).
[image: See the Normal Image]

Else if the List is too large, I can't see the "Dismiss" Button

[image: Please see the bottom side!!]

Kindly Help me!!, I tried to add a Button to Bottom of the  within the layout itself, Its showing correctly, But i wonder why this default way of showing a positiveButton is not displaying at all

Comment: `AlertDialog.Builder` has already an internal ListView and the setAdapter method. Just remove all the view inflated stuff and call `alertDialogBuilder.setAdapter(new CustomAdapterTagAbsentees(this,abs)`

Comment: @blackbelt Does this apply to a custom adapter ?

Comment: @blackbelt Perfect!!! i hav to remove alertDialogBuilder.setMessage() from the code !! ill post my final code as  Answer to my question, Thanks a lot :) :). But im having problem while implementing onClickListener!! The List consist of "Absentees" Object, So i cant do nothing with onClick()!!

Comment: take a look to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener))

Answer (score 1):

Use a RelativeLayout instead of a Linear.  Put the buttons to layout_alignParentBottom="true".  Put the listview to layout_above="id of button".  This will force the buttons to the bottom of the screen and reserve space for them before the listview is drawn.  Otherwise the listview is greedy and will suck up all the space needed.

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov Yes, probably.  Which you use is personal preference.  I like keeping it out of the list entirely because it deals with separate issues, but it would get the effect he wants.

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov Yes Ive tried it already, What im asking is: why the Button is not showing, if i set the Button by setPositveButton method!!

Comment: @GabeSechan, This one is about putting the Button with in the Layout, right ?

Comment: Ah, yes.  For some reason I wasn't thinking about the AlertDialog's positive and negative buttons.  For those, set a maxHeight for the listview.  That way it won't take up more than a screen in size.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for you assistance, But i got my problem solved by following blackbet's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final Solution for my problem, Thanks for @blackbelt for the suggestion

```
 private void showLogs(final List<Absentees> abs) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final ListAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapterTagAbsentees(this,abs);
    alertDialogBuilder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            showLogs(abs);
            Absentees a =(Absentees) adapter.getItem(item);
            showLogDetails(a);
        }
    });

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Attendance Details:");
    //alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Day : XXXX");
    alertDialogBuilder
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Dismiss",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
  AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
  alertDialog.show();
}
```

I have to comment/remove

```
 alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Day : XXXX ");
```

for succesfull implementation, Dont know why!!